# Javascript toggle visibility multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, visibility

http://blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/

this is a page with some code and a script im using in my site for an image gallery, however when trying to toggle the visibility of multiple div's it only works on the first. can someone please fix it to work with multiple div's, i dont know js :)

here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

and here is the html code for the links

```
<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('nyc');">New York</a></td>
<td><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('photoshop');">Photoshop Work</td>
<td><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('photography');">Photography</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('art');">Art Projects</td></tr>
```

wait a sec, could this not be working because it is trying to acess the properties of multiple divs via the "id" property, would it work with the class property and if so would i just change the java script where it says "id" to "class"

Comment: Can you show your code of multiple divs?

Comment: Any reason for `<!--`s in the script tags? Or are you targeting browsers older than Netscape 2?

Comment: Which divs do you want this to affect? Are you identify them with their `id` or with class-names?

Comment: Each id must be unique in the document. If you want to have more than one element with the same id, you should use classes instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you were trying something like

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="a"></div>

toggle_visibility('a');
```

The problem is that each id must be unique in the document, so `document.getElementById` returns a single element, not a collection of elements.

Then, if you want to have more than one element with the same id, you should use classes instead.

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>


function toggle_visibility(cl){
   var els = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
   for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
      var s = els[i].style;
      s.display = s.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
   }
}
toggle_visibility('a');
```

---

If you want to make it work with multiple classes, use

```
var toggle_visibility = (function() {
   function toggle(cl) {
       var els = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
       for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
          var s = els[i].style;
          s.display = s.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
       }
   }
   return function(cl) {
      if (cl instanceof Array){
         for(var i = 0; i < cl.length; i++){
            toggle(cl[i]);
         }
      } else {
         toggle(cl);
      }
   };
})();
toggle_visibility('myclass');
toggle_visibility(['myclass1','myclass2','myclass3']);
```

Comment: could you show me the code i would need to change, just the script and if i would need to change the buttons. I already changed all the elements to use the class tag.

Comment: @user2072017 Be aware that `document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't work on old browsers. See browser compatibility table here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName#Browser_compatibility

Comment: is there a way to make it work with more than one class  toggle_visibility('a','b','c');

Comment: @user2072017 Yes, I have updated my answer with that, based on my other answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17642471/1529630).

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   function toggle(id){
      var el = document.getElementById(id);
      el.style.display = el.style.display==='none' ? 'block' : 'none';
   }
   if(id instanceof Array){
      for(var i=0; i<id.length; ++i){
         toggle(id[i]);
      }
   }else{
      toggle(id);
   }
}
```

And call it like

```
toggle_visibility('myid');
toggle_visibility(['myid1','myid2','myid3']);
```

---

Another possible way is using `arguments` variable, but that could slow down your code

```
function toggle_visibility() {
   function toggle(id){
      var el = document.getElementById(id);
      el.style.display = el.style.display==='none' ? 'block' : 'none';
   }
   for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; ++i){
      toggle(arguments[i]);
   }
}
```

And call it like

```
toggle_visibility('myid');
toggle_visibility('myid1','myid2','myid3');
```

---

If you don't want to create the function `toggle` each time you call `toggle_visibility` (thanks @David Thomas), you can use

```
var toggle_visibility = (function(){
   function toggle(id){
      var el = document.getElementById(id);
      el.style.display = el.style.display==='none' ? 'block' : 'none';
   }
   return function(id){
      if(id instanceof Array){
         for(var i=0; i<id.length; ++i){
            toggle(id[i]);
         }
      }else{
         toggle(id);
      }
   };
})();
toggle_visibility('myid');
toggle_visibility(['myid1','myid2','myid3']);
```

Or

```
var toggle_visibility = (function(){
   function toggle(id){
      var el = document.getElementById(id);
      el.style.display = el.style.display==='none' ? 'block' : 'none';
   }
   return function(){
      for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; ++i){
         toggle(arguments[i]);
      }
   };
})();
toggle_visibility('myid');
toggle_visibility('myid1','myid2','myid3');
```

Comment: I like the approach, but you're creating/declaring a new `toggle()` function every time you call `toggle_visibility()` (which is a little needless).

Answer (score 0):

You either need to cycle through a list of ids or use a class name as the argument to toggle_visibilty ---- which means you would have to edit the function. It looks like right now you are only calling toggle_visibility on one element.

jQuery makes this kind of thing easier:

```
  <code>
  //selects all elements with class="yourClassName"
  jQuery(".yourClassName").toggle();

  //select all divs
   jQuery("div").toogle();

  //select all divs inside a container with id="myId"
 jQuery("#myId > div").toggle();
 </code>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very silly mistake in your code..
Add the `id` attribute in the td tags id='nyc', etc. and it should work fine