# Select all HTML table rows between two particular rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table that has rows something like this:

```
<tr class='department'><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
<tr><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
<tr><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
<tr><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
<tr class='departmentTotals'><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
```

I'd like to toggle the middle four rows when the top row is clicked.

Right now I am thinking I can loop through the rows using `$(this).next('tr')` until I get to the `departmentTotals` class, but is there a simple selector for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `nextUntil` method:

```
$(this).nextUntil('.departmentTotals')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the rows that you want to be toggled, then create a function that adds/removes a hide class to all the trs when you click the top row.

```
<tr class='department'><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr class='toggle'><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
<tr class='toggle'><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
<tr class='toggle'><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
<tr class='toggle'><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
<tr class='departmentTotals'><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
```

Then set up a toggle function similar to what is done in this post: [Javascript toggle visibility multiple divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642422/javascrip-toggle-visibility-multiple-divs)