# How hide a group of UI component

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have a group of component (for example `Label`+`TextArea`)

```xml
<Label text="Country"/>
<TextArea value="{model>/country}"/>
```

Now, to hide the group I'm forced to set the `visible` property for each component

```xml
<Label visible="false" text="Country" />
<TextArea visible="false" value="{model>/country}"/>
```

I would like hide the entire group by a sigle set of a property, for example by a 'container' with its property `visible`

```xml
<Container visible="false">
    <Label text="Country" />
    <TextArea value="{model>/country}"/>
</Container>
```

I have for example a `VerticalLayout` which contains a `Panel`, which contains a `SimpleForm`.
SimpleForm contains 4 couples `Label`-`TextArea` and I want group 1st and 2nd couple WITHOUT add additional margins or other ui properties

Comment: Stuff like Label and TextArea are "Controls" not "Components".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various container controls available in UI5. Panel, FlexBox, VerticalLayout, HorizontalLayout, SimpleForm etc.

```
<Panel visible="false">
  <content>
    <Label text="Country" />
    <TextArea value="{model>/country}"/>
  </content>
</Panel>
```

As an alternate & a better way instead of wrapping the controls within a parent control, you can create a model where you maintain the control visibility states.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({group1Visibile : false});
<view-instance>.setModel(oModel,"controlStates");

<Label text="Country" visible ="{controlStates>/group1Visible}"/>
<TextArea value="{model>/country}" visible ="{controlStates>/group1Visible}"/>
```

Just manipulating the values of the model will be reflected to all the controls.

Comment: Panel, FlexBox, VerticalLayout, HorizontalLayout, SimpleForm, etc , add additional ui style (for example add margins). I have for example a VerticalLayout which contains a Panel, which contains a SimpleForm.
SimpleForm contains 4 couples Label-TextArea and I want group 1st and 2nd couple WITHOUT add additional margins or other ui properties

Comment: You can add the css classes .sapUiNoContentPadding, .sapUiNoMargin to remove the margins and padding.
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html?sap-ui-debug=true#/entity/sap.ui.core.ContainerPadding/samples

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Javascript and style class (sorry for javascript view, I don't use xml much):

```js
var oLabel = new sap.m.Label({
    text:"Text", 
    labelFor: oText}).addStyleClass("hideGroup");
var oText = new sap.m.Text({
    text: "Hello World!"
}).addStyleClass("hideGroup");

var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
    text: "Press to Hide/Show Group",
    press: function(){
        var els = document.getElementsByClassName("hideGroup");
        for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i){
            var s = els[i].style;
            s.visibility = s.visibility==='visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a working JSBIN example: [LINK](http://jsbin.com/tumutemora/1/edit?html,output)
This is just an example, you can fit it to your needs.

For more info, take a look at this thread: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642422/javascript-toggle-visibility-multiple-divs)